# ArcGIS for iOS - How to stop seeing outside map

Tags: ios, arcgis, esri

In my project, I have an AGSMapView taking up the screen that starts zoomed out to show the entire world map. I have it set to wrap around horizontally, so it works fine there.

However, vertically I can see an empty gray grid at the top and bottom of the map. The user can also scroll the map and this grid can take up at most half the screen, at any zoom level so long as you're at the edge.

Is there any way to snap the edge of the map to the edge of the view it's embedded in and not show this ugly grid?

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [AGSMapView](https://developers.arcgis.com/ios/api-reference/interface_a_g_s_map_view.html).
maxEnveloppe is what you're looking for :

> Limits the amount by which the map can be panned such that its anchor point (typically the center) never goes outside this envelope. By default, this is the full envelope of the basemap layer. If you set a custom extent, the envelope must have the same spatial reference as the map.

By the way, you can easily restyle the grid backgroundColor, gridLineWidth, gridLineColor and gridSize. If you want to remove the grid effect, then you have to set the gridLineWidth to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to forum [Click here](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/57159) I found closer solution to this problem which worked for me. I have used method suggested by 'reedhr' which I am copying here.

```
- (void) removePanGesturesFromMap {

NSMutableArray * mutableGestureRecognizers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:MapView.gestureRecognizers];

NSMutableArray *recognizersToRemove = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (UIGestureRecognizer * gestureRecognizer in MapView.gestureRecognizers) {

    if (![gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UILongPressGestureRecognizer class]]

        && ![gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class]] ) {

        [recognizersToRemove addObject:gestureRecognizer];
    }
}

if (recognizersToRemove.count > 0) {

    [mutableGestureRecognizers removeObjectsInArray:(NSArray*) recognizersToRemove];

    MapView.gestureRecognizers = (NSArray*)mutableGestureRecognizers;
}
```

}